# Perl: sub cannot have my input successfully

Tags: perl

I have following command, and I put variables "$bus" and "$value" in sub busbitFill.

And the sub can eat $bus successfully, but $value is not working.
Please tell me where I was wrong....

```
....some code that generate $index, $bus and $value...


 print "index=$index\n bus=$bus\n value=$value\n";    #<=all variable printed successfully

 &busbitFill($bus, @array0, $value);                  
                                                         

sub busbitFill {
    my($bus, @array, $val) = @_;
    print "val1: $val\n";                    #<=but when $value goes into sub "busbitFill"
}                                            #  the sub cannot print $val 



<This is the printed result for first row in above code>
index=AA[0]
 
bus=[2:0]

value=110
```

Comment: Don't use `&` in sub calls. It's a special form of a sub call that does something special that you have no reason to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass arrays to subs, just scalars.

```perl
$bus, @array0, $value
```

is the same as

```perl
$bus, $array0[0], $array0[1], ..., , $array0[$#array], $value
```

So now, you have who knows how many elements in `@_` and you assign them to `$bus, @array, $val`. The first is assigned to `$buf`. But how many of the remaining arguments should be assigned to `@array`? Well, Perl has no way to know. So it assigns all remaining arguments to `@array`.

Pass a reference to the array instead.

```perl
sub busbitFill {
   my ( $bus, $array, $value ) = @_;
   ...
}

busbitFill( $bus, \@array0, $value );
```

Don't forget that `$array` is now a reference to an array rather than an array, and the code for the sub will have to take that into consideration.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that when the rest of the sub is implemented, `$array` will have to be dereferenced. Also that the same process may be used for hashes.

Comment: The simplest option might be to put the array last `my ($bus, $value, @array) = @_`.

Comment: @TLP It doesn't look like it's a list of things for the sub to work on, so I would still use a reference here, even if it was last.